# MYSQL SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: mysql, laravel, innodb

I have the code but not the local host that an error I can't understand help
MYSQL 5.7.21 INNODB
Code:

```
$sql = DB::select('
            SELECT 
                (case when (CAST(to as time) <= CAST("'.$time.'" as time) and 
                            CAST(do as time) >= CAST("'.$time.'" as time) or 
                            (to is null and do is null)) 
                             THEN
                                  1 
                             ELSE
                                  0 
                             END) as working
            FROM 
                franchises
    ');
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an 
error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to as time) <= 
CAST("10:15" as time) and CAST(do as time) >= CAST("10:15" as tim' at
line 2 (SQL:
```

Comment: is there any field like `to ` and `do`?

Comment: Yes there is such field

Comment: Is it working in `workbench` or `MYSQL`  console as a raw query?

Comment: @MayuriPansuriya Yes there is such field

Comment: @the.salman.a mysql works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`To` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-T) in MySQL, therefore you need to include it in backticks:

```
...case when (CAST(`to` as time)...
```